# Write message to folder on the disk using MailKit

Tags: c#, smtp, smtpclient, mailkit, mimekit

I'm trying to move an application that used System.Net.Mail over to MailKit/MimeKit.

Using System.NetMail, you could write messages to a folder like so:

```
_smtp = new SmtpClient()
{
    DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.SpecifiedPickupDirectory,
    PickupDirectoryLocation = path //path could be a string like "C:\Temp"
};

_smtp.Send(message);
```

Is there a solution to do this using MailKit/MimeKit?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, but it doesn't involve MailKit's SmtpClient...

Instead, you'd do this:

```
MimeKit.MimeMessage message = CreateMyMessage ();
message.WriteTo (fileName);
```